# Selecting a variable range and replacing blank fields with value "NA"

Tags: excel, vba, inputbox

I would like to have a button in my Excel sheet that:
1) Asks me to select the range I want to use
2) Changes the blank cells found in this range to a fixed value ("NA")

I could find how to get a box asking me to select a range, but not a solution on changing the values in combination with this box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SpecialCells()` to do this in only two lines:

```
Sub t()
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", Type:=8).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
rng.Value = "NA"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the range from your other existing get range value from a sub to a sub like this:

```
Private Sub BlankToNA(Target as Range)
     Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "NA"
End Sub
```